# Visualizing multiple curves in ggplot from bootstrapping, curve fitting

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

I have time series data that is well modeled using a sinusoidal curve. I'd like to visualize the uncertainty in the fitted model using bootstrapping.

I adapted the approach from [here.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/bootstrapping.html) I am also interested in this [approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172087/plot-bootstrapping-in-ggplot2) too, using `nlsBoot`. I can get the first approach to run, but the resulting plot contains curves that are not continuous, but jagged.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

xdata <- c(-35.98, -34.74, -33.46, -32.04, -30.86, -29.64, -28.50, -27.29, -26.00, 
           -24.77, -23.57, -22.21, -21.19, -20.16, -18.77, -17.57, -16.47, -15.35,
           -14.40, -13.09, -11.90, -10.47, -9.95,-8.90,-7.77,-6.80, -5.99,
           -5.17, -4.21, -3.06, -2.29, -1.04)
ydata <- c(-4.425, -4.134, -5.145, -5.411, -6.711, -7.725, -8.087, -9.059, -10.657,
           -11.734, NA, -12.803, -12.906, -12.460, -12.128, -11.667, -10.947, -10.294,
           -9.185, -8.620, -8.025, -7.493, -6.713, -6.503, -6.316, -5.662, -5.734, -4.984,
           -4.723, -4.753, -4.503, -4.200)

data <- data.frame(xdata,ydata)

bootnls_aug <- data %>% bootstrap(100) %>%
  do(augment(nls(ydata ~ A*cos(2*pi*((xdata-x_0)/z))+M, ., start=list(A=4,M=-7,x_0=-10,z=30),.)))
ggplot(bootnls_aug, aes(xdata, ydata)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted, group=replicate), alpha=.1, color="blue") +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_bw()
```

[ggplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTvbh.png)

Can anyone offer help? Why are the displayed curves not smooth? Is there a better way to implement?

Comment: You want to use `geom_smooth()` instead of `geom_line(), possibly with a custom `formula` arg

Comment: The examples both use geom_line(), so I'm not sure why my results are different.

Comment: they use `y=predict(fittedModel)` to compute the y values continously, while you are giving it a set of values (`.fitted`). This is the same as in the first example (you can see the line is not smooth in the last plot, cfr the different code between the second and last plot there). The second example just hide the not smoothness with lots of data point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`broom::augment` is merely returning fitted values for each of the available data points. Therefore, the resolution of `x` is limited to the resolution of the data. You can `predict` values from the model with a much higher resolution:

```
x_range <- seq(min(xdata), max(xdata), length.out = 1000)

fitted_boot <- data %>% 
  bootstrap(100) %>%
  do({
    m <- nls(ydata ~ A*cos(2*pi*((xdata-x_0)/z))+M, ., start=list(A=4,M=-7,x_0=-10,z=30))
    f <- predict(m, newdata = list(xdata = x_range))
    data.frame(xdata = x_range, .fitted = f)
    } )

ggplot(data, aes(xdata, ydata)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted, group=replicate), fitted_boot, alpha=.1, color="blue") +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Some more work is needed to add the mean and 95% confidence interval:

```
quants <- fitted_boot %>% 
  group_by(xdata) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(.fitted),
            lower = quantile(.fitted, 0.025),
            upper = quantile(.fitted, 0.975)) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(stat, value, -xdata)

ggplot(mapping = aes(xdata)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted, group = replicate), fitted_boot, alpha=.05) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value, lty = stat), col = 'red', quants, size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = ydata), data, size=3) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(lower = 2, mean = 1, upper = 2)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: From this, is there an easy way to derive confidence bands?

Comment: Just compute the quantiles.

Comment: From something like this? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best

Comment: Yeah, you need something like their `quants <- apply(boot.pdf, 1, quantile, c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975))`.

Comment: Thank you, yes. I've been messing around with that line, but still am not clear what to do with it.

Comment: When I run your code, I get the following error after the 'quants' portion: "Error: Position must be between 0 and n"

Comment: Works fine over here. Perhaps update your `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages to the latest CRAN versions.

Comment: Okay! That worked! It's incredible how just a few days stale package can throw a wrench in it all! Thank you!!!

Comment: The request for "easy way to derive confidence bands" made me think of the `fda`-package ('fda' is an initialism for "functional data analysis").